# How to filter objects in NSArray by object's property

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have a object called MyObject, with 2 properties MyObject.name, MyObject.ID
I also have a NSMutableArray object MyObjects to store MyObject object instances.

Now, I want to filter out all instances which MyObject.name contain char @"a" in MyObjects, how can I do it? I try the NSDictionary & NSPredicate methods but all failed.

Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but here is an idea off the top of my head.  You could loop through all the objects in the MyObjects NSMutable array and then write logic to search for @"a" in each MyObject.name and then store those that don't contain @"a" in a new array.

```
// note using ARC
NSMutableArray *myFilteredObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(MyObject *myObject in MyObjects)
{
    NSRange *range = [myObject.name rangeOfString:@"a"];

    if(range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        // add object to new array if it doesn't contain @"a"
        [myFilteredObjects addObject: myObject];
    }
}

// do what you want with filtered objects array
```